# Which data structure can store OIDs

Tags: list, tree, snmp

I like to store SNMP OIDs in a data structure which allows me to search in it. A binary tree or linked list is not correct?

The data structure must support one parent node with many child nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SNMP OIDs are organized in a hierarchical n-ary tree structure. Therefore, using a linked list will not let you search for a specific OID very fast (you would have to loop from the beginning of the list to the matched OID, one by one). A binary structure could work, but mapping a n-ary tree to a binary tree would need some lines of code.

I suggest you to use a data structure library, instead of doing the job by yourself. Depending on the language you are programming in, you may find different implementations of a same Key/Value store and search API. For instance, with Java, you will find many implementations of the same Map interface: some based on hash tables, some based on trees, some based on linked-lists, etc. For your performance needs, and because of the OID tree structure, you should avoid linked-lists. The others have pros and cons.